# Mediaplayer stops after 5 seconds on new Activity

Tags: java, android

I have 2 Activities a main one which starts a mediaplayer stream, and a button leading to starts Activity #2 and then finish() the current Activity the tasks for Activity #1 are completed at this point, musicplayer gives no problem at this point. After the Activity #2 is opened however, the mediaplayer works for about 5 seconds and then it stops, in Activity #2 I only have a button to exit and an AsyncTask running in a loop with the help of a Handler.

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but why are you calling finish on Activity 1 before you open Activity 2? You should just open activity 2, and let the user close activity 2 with the back button on the device, which will bring activity 1 back to the front. Finishing and closing activities manually breaks the expected navigation flow of your application.

Comment: post the code so we can see it.

Comment: @jlindenbaum : Calling `finish()` on an `Activity` is perfectly acceptable so long as you do it for the right reason, i.e., if you don't want to return to that `Activity` again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're MediaPlayer from Activity 1 is being wiped from memory since you're calling `finish()`.  The `MediaPlayer` instance is part of the first `Activity`.  The only way to fix this is to start a new `MediaPlayer` in your Activity 2 or create a `Service` that handles all media in the background.  If you do it the second way, the one MediaPlayer instance will remain playing through all your activities and you only need to send commands to it.

Comment: Understood and this seems to fit my scenario. Do you have an example of either of these methods suggested? Thank you.

Comment: It's not much different than what you're doing now.  The first method may require you send a `Bundle` in the `Intent` to tell the Activity which sound was playing, volume, etc.  The second method would be similar to this: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

Comment: Thanks again, this helped me out on my conquest! lol, approved answer as it was helpful in my situation